# Getting variables from wildcard routes

Tags: node.js, express

I've got a node app using the express server and I'm struggling with the routing. 'Browse' is the function and 'type', 'subtype' and 'name' are variables. If I have a route like:

```
/browse/type/subtype/name
```

then I can pick that up with:

```
/browse/:type/:subtype/:name
```

...so the vars show up separately in the req.params object. Sometimes, however, not all of the vars will appear, so you may get a url like:

```
/browse/cars
```

I want a route that catches them all, but if I use a wildcard then req.params will not pick them up as separate parameters. My best guess was something like:

```
/browse(/:type)?(/:subtype)?(/:name)?
```

Anyone know how this should be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/browse/:type?/:subtype?/:name?` should work